# Changing the size of the turtlesim window

Tags: ros, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I change the canvas width and canvas height of the turtlesim window displayed on running turtlesim_node? Are there some options which can be used with the command "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node __name:=turtle1" to change the size of the display window.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63211/changing-the-size-of-the-turtlesim-window/) by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlesim does not support a dynamic windows size.

This is mainly due to keeping the code as simple as possible since turtlesim is used as an example/tutorial for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-23**:
+1          second that